# How to get Id of the created record when using .submit function

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, html5

How do i get the record ID of the newly created record when i use `this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit()` and store it in a variable?

Comment: This is [from the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) -- *To return the Id, use the `onsuccess` handler*. Are you facing issues using this?

Answer (score 5):

According to docs `Returning the Record Id` [LWC documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation), record ID is returned via `onsuccess` handler. Example given below same as doc.

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account" onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input-field field-name='Id' value={accountIdToBeShown}></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name='Name'></lightning-input-field>
            <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                <lightning-button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Create Account">
                </lightning-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

JS:

```
export default class CustomSearchSobjectLwc extends LightningElement {

    accountIdToBeShown;
    handleSuccess(event) {
        console.log(event.detail.id);
        this.accountIdToBeShown = event.detail.id;
    }
}
```